# setTitle() function is making crash my program if not hardcoded String

Tags: c, gcc, c99

Since now I'm programming on my Maze game for College. I am almost ready. Just need to beautify it.

Here I thought 'bout making a setTitle function. Whenever testing it, it had some strange symptomps I've never seen.

So if I hardcode the title[255] array, title will be appended onto the cmd array. When setting the title as parameter in the function, and I give the value over to setTitle(char title[255]) (e.g. "*** MAZE RUNNER***"), the program crashes.

I've tried different array sizes, but this symptom seems to appear randomly.

Maybe a beginner fault at my side?

```
void setTitle(char title[255]) {
    char cmd[] = "title ";
    strcat(cmd, title);
    system(cmd);
}

int main() {
    setTitle("Hello Stackoverflow! I hope you can help me! feelssadman:(");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have enough space to store/concat `title` into `cmd`, switch to `char cmd[255 + 6] = "title ";`

Comment: When you declare an array like `char arr[] = "Hello"` the compiler counts the length of the length of the string (in this case "Hello") and puts it into the `[]`. In the end, it will be transformed to `char arr[6] = "Hello"`. In your case, the size of the `cmd[]` array is 7 so you cannot append any other thing to it.

Comment: Also, stop typing constants when passing arrays as parameters. When you have `void setTitle(char title[255])` the compiler ignores `255` and will treat it as `void setTitle(char title[])`. In the end, `title` is just a constant pointer to some array of `char`s so the actual declaration behind it is `void setTitle(const char* title)`. People usually use the `[]` so that it is clear that the function needs an array and not a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your function is simple; the size allocated for the array `cmd` is autocompleted by the compiler with the length of the initialised string. To make your function work, just place some constant between the `[]` when declaring the `cmd` string.

```
void setTitle(char title[]) {
    char cmd[255] = "title ";
    strcat(cmd, title);
    system(cmd);
}
```

Also keep in mind that the `255` is not needed when you declare the function parameter. Is is ignored by the compiler. You can also replace it with `void setTitle(const char* title)` (which is in fact what `title` actually is) but it is more commonly and conventional to declare it as `title[]` when you want an array.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll remember.